# Best way to get data from ApiController and pass it to another view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

So i have an ApiController set up that takes a search query, and returns JSON in this case.

I also have a search form on my _Layout.cshtml page. When the user searches for anything, I have ajax that successfully hits my ApiController method and returns JSON, but I'm unsure what to do with it. I want to redirect to /SearchResults/ and display the results, but I can't help but feel I'm going out of my way using WebApi's and that I should just cut that out.

Does it make sense to have hit the ApiController from my search button, then send the results to another View? How can I redirect to that other View?

```
$('#btnSearch').click(function () {
            var query = $('#searchQuery').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/api/search",
                data: {query : query},
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'application/json',
                statusCode: {
                    200: function (queryResult) {
                        //I want to send queryResult to another view
                    },
                    404: function () {
                        alert("failure");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're asking the question and for good reason, what you describe feels awkward and in fact it is.  Hitting the WebAPI is good practice as you're keeping the payload for searches very small (passing data only and not HTML).  What you really want to do, is NOT request another view i.e. when statusCode is 200 what you want to do is render HTML on the client side inside the current view.  This of course is easily done in JQuery which from your code snippet looks like you're already using.

**Yes, it does make sense to have hit the ApiController from my search button"**

In your search page add some JavaScript that that dynamically updates the section of the page with the search results you want displayed from the search result data you got back from the WebAPI.  **Don't fire yet another web request to get another view/page.**